# Lock the memory to physical RAM in C for the dynamically allocate pointer

Tags: c, posix, memory-locking

I want to lock the memory to physical RAM in C with `mlock` and `munlock`, but I'm unsure about the correct usage.

Allow me to explain in a step by step scenario:

Let's assume that I dynamically allocate a pointer using `calloc`:

```
char * data = (char *)calloc(12, sizeof(char*));
```

Should I do `mlock` right after that?

Let's also assume that I later attempt to resize the memory block with `realloc`:

```
(char *)realloc(data, 100 * sizeof(char*));
```

Note the above increase amount ( 100 ) is random and sometimes i will decrease the memory block.

Should I first do `munlock` and then `mlock` again to address the changes made?

Also when I want to free the pointer `data` later, should I `munlock` first?

I hope someone can please explain the correct steps to me so I can understand better.

Comment: You can by accident unlock nearby pages, so I would say you shouldn't mix `mlock` and `malloc`. Use `mmap`.

Comment: You have allocated the wrong (too much) memory size with `char * data = (char *)calloc(12, sizeof(char*));` It should be `char * data = (char *)calloc(12, sizeof(*data));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the POSIX specification of [`mlock()` and `munlock()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mlock.html):

> The `mlock()` function shall cause those whole pages containing any part
>   of the address space of the process starting at address `addr` and
>   continuing for `len` bytes to be memory-resident until unlocked or until
>   the process exits or execs another process image. The implementation
>   may require that `addr` be a multiple of `{PAGESIZE}`.
>
> The `munlock()` function shall unlock those whole pages containing any
>   part of the address space of the process starting at address `addr` and
>   continuing for `len` bytes, regardless of how many times `mlock()` has
>   been called by the process for any of the pages in the specified
>   range. The implementation may require that `addr` be a multiple of
>   `{PAGESIZE}`.

Note that:

- Both functions work on whole pages
- Both functions might require `addr` to be a multiple of page size
- `munlock` doesn't use any reference counting to track lock lifetime

This make it almost impossible to use them with pointers returned by `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc` as they can:

- Accidently lock/unlock nearby pages (you might unlock pages that must be memory-resident by accident)
- Might return pointers that are not suitable for those functions

You should use `mmap` instead or any other OS-specific mechanism. For example Linux has `mremap` which allows you to "reallocate" memory. Whatever you use, make sure `mlock` behavior is well-defined for it. From Linux [man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mremap.2.html) pages:

> If the memory segment specified by `old_address` and `old_size` is locked
>   (using `mlock(2)` or similar), then this lock is maintained when the
>   segment is resized and/or relocated.  As a consequence, the amount of
>   memory locked by the process may change.

---

Note [Nate Eldredge's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/634919/nate-eldredge) comment below:

> Another problem with using `realloc` with locked memory is that the data
>   will be copied to the new location before you have a chance to find
>   out where it is and lock it. If your purpose in using `mlock` is to
>   ensure that sensitive data never gets written out to swap, this
>   creates a window of time where that might happen.

Comment: Thank you very much. But why such example use malloc if almost impossible: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_MRG/1.3/html/Realtime_Reference_Guide/sect-Realtime_Reference_Guide-Memory_allocation-Using_mlock_to_avoid_memory_faults.html

Comment: @JorhnMadsen It is impossible not as if it won't work, it is hard to make sure you don't get in trouble later (e.g. hard to use correctly). Consider situation when you have 2 memory chunks in the same page. Using `munlock` before moving the first chunk to a new place might leave the 2nd chunk unlocked. Things might work if you allocate once, lock, then never release the memory.

Comment: @JorhnMadsen: Because the people who write examples sometimes simplify too much or make mistakes.

Comment: I get your point. The reason behind using calloc was to port it later to Windows ( by using VirtualLock in same manner  )

Comment: @JorhnMadsen Windows has `VirtualAlloc` and `MapViewOfFile`. But you might need to forget about `mremap`. Creating thin OS-compatibility layer shouldn't be hard.

Comment: Another problem with using `realloc` with locked memory is that the data will be copied to the new location before you have a chance to find out where it is and lock it.  If your purpose in using `mlock` is to ensure that sensitive data never gets written out to swap, this creates a window of time where that might happen.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thats a good point. I have added your note to my answer.

Comment: So the correct ( safe) way is:  mmap() instead of malloc(),  mremap() instead of using realloc() and munmap() instead of free() ?

Comment: @JorhnMadsen Yes. Technically, `malloc`/`calloc` might work if you allocate, lock and never `realloc` or `munlock` that memory ever again.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain to me! You all have been helpfull. Wish to accept al, but can't and @StaceyGirl you did very good explain!

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR

1. Memory locking doesn't mix with general-purpose memory allocation using the C language runtime.
2. Memory locking does mix with page-oriented virtual memory mapping OS-level APIs.
3. The above hold unless special circumstances arise (that's my way out of this :)